# How to add select input box and textarea using angular2-mdl?

Tags: angular, angular2-mdl

I am using angular2-mdl for my project and did not find any way to integrate textarea or select option.
How to add select input box and textarea using angular2-mdl?

Answer (score 1):

For now angular2-mdl has no custom way to implement a select element but instead has an extended version which is yet to be released. You can see the project @ [www.github.com/mseemann/angular2-mdl-ext](http://www.github.com/mseemann/angular2-mdl-ext)

You can implement the default select element for now:

```
<select>
  <option>Mdl</option>
</select>
```

You can implement a textarea element like this:

```
<mdl-textfield label="Text..." rows="3" maxrows="3" floating-label></mdl-textfield>
```

See the e2e test app @ http://mseemann.io/angular2-mdl for more implementation.